# jQuery selector path bug on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

On IE8, jQuery version 1.4.2 return 0(when length is checked) for the following selector path but with version 1.9.1 it returns 1.

```
selectorPath = 'DIV#header + DIV > TABLE:first-child > TBODY:first-child > 
                TR:first-child > TD:first-child > TABLE:first-child > 
                TBODY:first-child > TR:first-child > TD:first-child > 
                TABLE:first-child > TBODY:first-child > TR:first-child > 
                TD:first-child > DIV:first-child + P + P + P + P + P + P 
                + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + 
                P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P 
                + P + P + P + P + P + P + H2 + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + 
                P + P';

$_1_4_2(selectorPath).length //returns 0

$_1_9_1(seelctorPath).length //returns 1
```

Can someone point me to the exact bug which covers this issue, or atleast a list of possibly related selector path bugs on version 1.4.2

Comment: Depends on the strucutre of the HTML, but anyways what kind of sick selector is this?

Comment: That is a MONSTROUS selector. Is that really the simplest it can be? I doubt it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is the shortest I could make it. Its an auto-genrated selector path for a webpage, so, I can't use a different selector path. I just need to find how its fixed in later versions of jQuery so that I can create a patch for jQuery 1.4.2(I can't update the jQuery version).

Comment: try running it in pieces to find out where it is failing

Answer (score 0):

try to divide it to couple of pieces..

```
selectorPath = 'DIV#header + DIV > TABLE:first-child > TBODY:first-child > 
                    TR:first-child > TD:first-child > TABLE:first-child > 
                    TBODY:first-child > TR:first-child > TD:first-child > 
                    TABLE:first-child > TBODY:first-child > TR:first-child > 
                    TD:first-child > DIV:first-child + P + P + P + P + P + P 
                    + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + 
                    P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + P 
                    + P + P + P + P + P + P + H2 + P + P + P + P + P + P + P + 
                    P + P';

    var half_len = Math.floor(selectorPath.length/2)                
    var first_part = selectorPath.substring(0, half_len);
    var second_part = selectorPath.substring(half_len, selectorPath.length);

    $_1_4_2(first_part).filter(second_part).length
```